# Html.BeginForm trying to pass id

Tags: c#, razor, html-helper

I used to have a form for uploading a file and it was working fine, but to my surprise it wasn't binding the HttpPostedFileBase to the model any more. After a while I realized that it was because I had changed from

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddDocument", "Documents", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "addTab" }))
```

to

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddDocument", "Documents", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "addForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "addTab" }))
```

So I changed to (I tried just removing the @ of the id but it didn't work neither)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddDocument", "Documents", new {id= "addForm"}, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "addTab" }))
```

and it worked again.

So I thought I was doing the wrong thing for a lot of time, and I've changed the other forms in my solution. But it turned out that if I use

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Events", new {id = "editForm"}, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "addTab" }))
```

instead of

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddContact", "Contacts", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "addForm", @class = "addTab" }))
```

I'm not able to set the id (nor using other options)

I'm trying to make up my mind with [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) but I don't even know whether the id should be consider a route value or a html attribute, what the @ is for, used sometimes and sometimes not and specially why I lost the binding in the multipart case

Update:

This is the view (I've tried with the commented out code with the same result):

```
@model AddDocumentViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddDocument", "Documents", new {id= "addForm"}, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "addTab" }))
{   
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Please correct the errors and try again.")
    <div id="addDocumentdetails">
        <div>

            @*<input id="File" type="file" name="File" data-val-required="Please select a file" data-val="true" />*@
            @*@Html.ValidationMessage("File")*@
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new { type = "file" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.File)
            <span class="right">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OwnedItemId, Model.Plans, "Not attached to a plan..")</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Description,
                                new { @class = "addNotes", data_placeholders_focus = "false", placeholder = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Description)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="addDEC">
        <input class="addDECButton" type="submit" value="Save" />
    </div>
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class AddDocumentViewModel
{
    [Display(Prompt = "Document notes")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [StringLength(500, ErrorMessage = "Must be 500 characters or less")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int? OwnedItemId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Plans { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select a file")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddDocument()
{
    var partyId = (int)Session["PartyId"];
    var viewModel = _createBuilder.Build(partyId);
    return PartialView("_AddDocument", viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddDocument(AddDocumentViewModel viewModel)
{
    var partyId = (int)Session["PartyId"];

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _documentsManager.AddDocument(viewModel, partyId);

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            return Json(new { passedValidation = true, action = Url.Action("DocumentList") });

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    var newViewModel = _createBuilder.Rebuild(viewModel, partyId);
    return PartialView("_AddDocument", newViewModel);

}
```

Comment: id is most definitely an html attribute. unless of course you have routing setup to use an id system.

Comment: Ok, that's my understanding as well and that's why I always put it in the "last" position. But why is the binding working now for the file upload one then and not having id or @id there?

Comment: Do you want the Id as a route value (passed back to the controller) or as an html attribute on your form?

Comment: Ideally I would need it as an html attribute, but in case I put it in the last parameter (both with and withour @) I lose the binding for the file. For achieving this properly I need to use the third one and skip the id as html attribute. Don't get me wrong, I could find an easy workaround but I don't get it.

Comment: Hm. Adding an Id to the form (as an htmlattribute) shouldn't change the binding of the posted file. Are you just using a simple file input? Maybe if you posted your html and controller the reason would be obvious.

Comment: As for the @ being needed or not, I think it is unnecessary except for the class tag as that is a c# keyword.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure it's something wrong on my side but I can't see it

Comment: This is the html generated with the second option<form action="/Documents/AddDocument" class="addTab" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="addForm" method="post">